# how to write timestamp on output pictures with this code (ffmpeg)

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\aaaa\bbb\cccc\dddd\abc.ts" -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,18)),scale=200:100,tile=12x12" "D:\aaaa\bbb\cccc\dddd\tile.png"
```

I'm using windows `cmd` but I want to use a batch script as well.

How can I make a timestamp of pictures?

Comment: Batch is, mostly, just a list of commands in a row, to be processed in order. What have you tried?

Comment: According to the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169916/can-ffmpeg-burn-in-time-code), drawing the timestamps may require some programming (or relatively complex script). Please add an example for "burning" timestamps on a video (without `tile`).